# How to read Big files (~300 MB) from Google Cloud Storage?

Tags: java, file, google-app-engine, google-cloud-storage, blobstorage

I can easily `upload/write` or `Read` contents of files (~80KB) from [`Google Cloud Storage`](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/java/googlestorage/)

Now, I have to perform a bigger task while serving big files (~200MB-300MB) :

1) Need to read the contents of uploaded file into chunks (~10 KB).

```
       <--Want to modify chunked data programmatically-->
```

2) Repeat the "1" steps until stream read the whole content of the file (from starting to end sequentially).

I tried [this](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/java/googlestorage/#Java_Complete_sample_app) program but in response i only some amount of data. How to perform mentioned task?

Answer (score 1):

You should not use the file API (which is deprecated - see comment at the top of the page you mentioned). Instead use the GCS client (mentioned in the deprecation notice). The GCS client allows you to read continuously and you can serialize the state of the GcsInputChannel between requests until read was completed (if read is longer than request timeout). You should also consider using the mapreduce library and use the GoogleCloudStorageLineInput for reading the file and writing the modified one in your mapper (probably map-only in your case).

Comment: I tried to use GCS client but I don't know where to set `AppEngine Application ID` to host the project at `App-Engine`?

I am using GCS client due to ` prefetch buffer` :
https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/java/googlecloudstorageclient/getstarted

Comment: I am not sure I understand the question. Do you have difficulties accessing the bucket from your App Engine application?

Comment: Please have a look at : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25704937/openprefetchingreadchannel-is-not-working-in-google-cloud-storage-client-api

Comment: The referenced issue does not talk about APPLICATION ID. In any case replied to the other one as well.